# /bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, oracle, docker

I get this error when I try starting my oracle-xe-21.3 docker container

/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm able ro confirm that the file it's complaining of actually exist on my linux sever when I run this command ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Please what should be the cause of this error? I have rebuilt the oracle image but still no solution.

Comment: Is your docker image using alpine linux or any distribution using musl instead of gnu libc? Try to diagnoze it with ldd /bin/bash

Comment: Thanks for your reply This is what I got after running the ~$ ldd /bin/bash command:

    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff59af6000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f7e97736000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7e97730000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e9753e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e9789f000)

Comment: It is strange indeed! Seems to be finding all the libs!